How to set a keyframe as new rest pose with two armatures (fps)?
I have an fps model with two armatures with arm and weapon animations and the rest pose is the first frame of the animations.
I've already tried to join the armatures and simply put a keyframe as rest pose and put animations in the NLA Editor but I can't.
How to choose a frame from these two armatures as a new rest pose?
I'm a beginner
